# Программа для извлечения тех данных из видео файлов

Tags: видео

Нужна программа, которая умеет из списка видео файлов доставать тех данные и предоставляет возможность скопировать эти данные к себе, а не только просмотреть.

Comment: Какие данные надо извлечь?

Comment: продолжительность, разрешение, формат

Answer (score 1):

В пакетах с кодеками такие програмы идут, только нужно выбирать не для обычных пользователей пакет, а тот, что имеет больше размер и приписку "для кодирования видео", "для экспертов" и тому подобное.
Также неплохо скачать virtualdub, который очень легко гуглится и позволит делать некоторые вещи (например переконвертировать в другой формат или сохранить видео в виде массива картинок)